# git merge between different repositories

Tags: git, git-svn, git-merge, git-patch

I created a repository with git-svn from a big svn repository (git svn clone).
I've several local commits in my git repository that I don't need to push to svn but I will need to get updates from it.

Now I realized that I don't need the entire svn history in my local repository, since it's using too much space (some Gb) and that I should have used the -r option in the clone command to select a starting point.

I'd linke to start over with a new repository and then merge all the local commits from the old repository, but I'm not sure there is a simple way to do this.

The situation is this:

log of the old repository:

- local commit 10
- local commit 9
  ...
- local commit 1
- svn revision X
- svn revision X-1
  ...
- svn revision 1

the new repository has just one commit, corresponding to the contend of the revision X of the svn repository.

I tried to use format-patch and apply commands but I'm not sure on how to do this.

Is there a way to do what I need?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is, in your new repository:

- to `git remote add old` your old repository;
- to `git fetch old`;
- to checkout the branch which contains you want;
- to know the starting point from where your branch was created before the changes;
- and then use `git rebase --onto`.

When done, `git remote rm` the old repo and `git gc`.

See `git help rebase` for the `--onto` option: it is very, very useful.

Comment: I followed your method with one variation to make it more efficient. Instead of adding the old repository to the new one I added the new repository to the old one and pushed changes after the rebase.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could begin with checking out the revision X from the SVN repository and getting rid of all SVN-related folders. Then `git init && git add . && git commit -m "Importing revision X from SVN"`. Now you've got a Git repository with a snapshot of SVN's revision X.

Afterwards you could use `git format-patch` to create patches from your old Git repository. `git format-patch x..` where `x` is the commit equivalent to revision X from SVN. It will generate patch files. Execute it in the old Git repository.

Subsequently, in the new repository you can `git am all_those_patches.*` to get them applied in the new repository.

Cf. [`man git-am`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-am), [`man git-format-patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-format-patch).

Comment: Yep, much more space efficient than mine. Actually I wondered about `git am` but I remember now that format-patch generates in order, so globbing will yield them in the correct order.

Comment: If I understand I can replace the first step with `git clone -r <rev> <url>`, right? I tried to follow your instructions but when I `do git am ...` I get the following error for the first patch: `Applying: commit log
error: patch failed: some/path/filename.xml:12
error: some/path/filename.xml: patch does not apply
Patch failed at 0001 commit log
When you have resolved this problem run "git am --resolved".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git am --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop patching run "git am --abort".`